How do I calculate the appropriate size resistor (power & ohms) to shunt current while testing a 3A fuse?
Background
I bought some fuses online which are rated at 32V & 3A. (see image)
Two of these cost me $8.50USD at the local Lowes but I bought 50 of them online for $7USD.
The fuse goes into my furnace & I'd like to know it will fail at 3A.
Test The Fuse
I want to create a test harness to gradually increase current through one of the fuses and see it fail at 3A.
I have a desktop power supply and a multimeter I can use as an ammeter (included in circuit below).
Attempt To Limit Current
However, I want to insure my desktop power supply doesn't get too much current across it and I asked Copilot how I could create a circuit to test the fuse while implementing a shunt for "extra current.
Copilot AI
Copilot gave me the text explanation of a circuit which I turned into the schematic below.
A Few Missing Details
There were a few missing details however and I'm hoping someone can help me with these.

How much power would need to be dissipated thru R1?  How many watts?  What would the calculation be for that?
I know that P = EI etc.
How much power would R2 have to be able to handle? I have some 1/4 watt resistors?  If the power dissipated needs to be 1 Watt, can I put four resistors there in parallel?
Does this circuit look correct (would it shunt current properly)? Or does it look entirely wrong?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

TLDR; Copilot Text Explanation of the Circuit
Here's the text explanation that Copilot provided.
Steps to Build and Test:

Connect the Power Supply: Connect the positive terminal of the power supply to the positive terminal of the ammeter.

Insert the Ammeter: Connect the negative terminal of the ammeter to one end of the resistor.

Add the Resistor: Connect the other end of the resistor to one terminal of the fuse.

Connect the Fuse: Connect the other terminal of the fuse back to the negative terminal of the power supply.

Add the Shunt Resistor: Connect one end of the shunt resistor to the junction between the resistor and the fuse.

Connect the Transistor: Connect the other end of the shunt resistor to the collector of the NPN transistor. Connect the emitter of the transistor to the negative terminal of the power supply.

Base of the Transistor: Connect the base of the transistor to the junction between the resistor and the fuse through a small resistor (e.g., 1kΩ) to limit the base current.

Set the Power Supply: Adjust the power supply to a low voltage setting initially.

Increase the Current: Gradually increase the voltage to raise the current through the circuit. Monitor the ammeter to ensure the current is increasing.


10 Observe the Fuse: Continue to increase the current until it reaches 3A. The fuse should blow (open the circuit) when the current exceeds 3A. If the current exceeds the safe limit, the transistor will turn on and shunt the excess current through the shunt resistor, protecting the power supply.


The circiut is nonsense.  Since the transistor's base resistor is connected to the emitter, the transistor will not conduct.  With R1 = 1K, you will only get 1 mA through the fuse - you'd need 3000 volts to get 3 Amp.

It's reckless to save money on safety barriers. And when they are as cheap as $4 1/4?

OK, let's say you test a fuse or three from those cheap knock-off variants. Fuse testing will be destructive testing. How do you know that the next unit will be close in performance to the ones you tested? You really don't have any other reason than the manufacturers word for it.

@MrGerber - you are assuming and you know that about the word assume.
It isn't reckless - the original board inside the furnace that is past the step down transformer -- which supplies power to the internal board uses this smaller fuse and saves the board from frying.  I have no reason to believe the fuses aren't ok, (they are UL marked) but whenever I order things online I like to know.  I knew this question would cause some people to blow their own fuses.

@MrGerber  for your 2nd question -- "How do you know that the next unit will be close in performance to the ones you tested? "  My answer is: I was going to test all of them.

With all due respect. I'm not assuming. There is a reason for the specification of the fuse from the manufacturer of the furnace. Buying cheaper, either lower spec or no-brand components are compromising the safety barriers - unless you knew exactly what you were doing - but then there would not be any reason to ask the question in the first place. This question is what is assuming. It's assuming that a chatbot knows anything about Electronics engineering (ps: it doesn't!)

For the second question - if you test all the fuses, you have no fuses left. You burn $7, and have essentially learned nothing, and still haven't got any replacement fuses.

@MrGerber - I agree with you that the chatbot knows nothing.  That's also why i appreciate you and others here who've helped me think this through and for double-checking the total falsehood that the chatbot has provided.  Thanks agian.

@raddevus I think the quality of the question is included in the downvotes. You are citing a chatbot that told you nonsense and you are asking about that nonsense you might not otherwise be asking about, but just about how to test cheap potentially counterfeit fuses. At least some sanity check would have been in order, like the requirement of a 3000V supply for testing a 32V fuse, the fuse can't extinquish the arc.

@raddevus - Hi, It's too late to change things now since the question has received answers. But FYI, site members voted that questions asking about AI responses are off-topic, due to the wasted time they cause while people explain the AI mistakes. This was clearly shown by voting on the Meta question here. This question is a variant of that, since the question relies on an AI-generated circuit, whose low quality has caused flags etc. (I know that site policy could be more visible - I'm working on it.) Please note for next time.

@SamGibson Ah, that makes more sense.  I appreciate you explaining that. I didn't know about the AI rule.  I think the question still has value though.  But, I'm alone in that I suppose.

@raddevus To your credit, you are at least entertaining the idea that the AI could be wrong instead of insisting that it has somehow discovered an entirely new circuit topology that half a dozen electrical engineers say will never work.

In addition to the circuit problems that other posters have described the basic concept is flawed.
A 3A fuse is designed to pass the rated current indefinitely and will take a very long time to blow if the current only exceeds the rating by a small amount - potentially many hours.
Blowing the fuse in one second will require about 4.5A through it. Please view the chart from a Littelfuse data sheet (Complete datasheet). Your circuit needs to be able to provide many amps beyond the fuse rating

I would just connect the fuse directly in series with an ammeter connected to a power supply that is adjustable from 0-5V. No resistor is needed, the wires and meter would provide adequate resistance.

Excellent answer.  I appreciate it very much.

The whole thing may be pointless. If your furnace has a fuse, you need to do other things too than match the current. You need to match voltage as well, you can't replace a 250VAC fuse with 32VAC fuse, and you need to match more subtle characteristics such as fast or slow blow to avoid blowing too fast or too slowly. And the breaking current ability - you can't replace a fuse that can handle 1000A safely and extinquish the arc with a fuse that can only handle 10A safely and 1000A would keep arcing over.
Having said that, here are the answers for your questions.

With 1k resistor and you wanting 3A to flow, it requires 3000V supply. You likely don't have one, at least ot would be very dangerous if you have one. The supply would need to provide 9000 watts and the resistor would need to dissipate it. The supply would need a 120V 75A feed, or about 40 amps at 230V. That's somewhat more than average household main fuses are rated, depending on where you live.

None, as no current will flow through R2 in that circuit. The transistor can never turn on.

No it does not look correct at all.



"you can't replace a 250VAC fuse with 32VAC fuse" -- well it's not 250VAC - it is a little mini-board (controller) that is after the DC transformer (inside the furnace) steps the voltage down to 24V DC.  So that's not a proper assumption.  I knew the idea of my question would blow some fuses here, but's that's always fun too.

@raddevus Did you read the whole answer or stopped at "250VAC"? It was just an example what you can't do among others, I never assumed your circuit is mains operated, as you did not tell any details like the actual voltage. 32V fuse should be fine in a 24V circuit. But what about the rest of the stuff?

Yes, I did read the entire answer and also, I upvoted your answer. But since you downvoted me, I guess I should'a downvoted you too, right? Sheesh.

No one, it was a joke.


Does this circuit look correct (would it shunt currnet properly)? Or does it look entirely wrong?

Unfortunately, the circuit looks entirely wrong. Assuming your power supply provides 12 V, R1 would already limit the current to 12 mA, even in the best case of the shunt.
LLMs, like Copilot and other tools, are not well-equipped to handle circuits whatsoever. AFAIK they generally do not have the ability to form a circuit in graph form and "reason" about it, and essentially only string together words and phrases without ever forming a coherent circuit structure internally.

If you do not need gradual ramping, the simplest circuit in principle is a power supply, the fuse, and a resistor. The problem is the hefty power dissipation, which requires a power resistor depending on the voltage.
Even if we took the lowest-voltage rail available from your typical PC power supply (3.3V), we'd need a roughly 1-ohm resistor, dissipating 3 W. This isn't an awful amount of power, but still sizable that whatever resistors you have on hand probably won't work. Needless to say, the resistance of your wires and fuse will also be relevant.
If you then need to ramp the current, switching in parallel resistors to decrease the resistance is the simplest approach.

That is an excellent answer & provides a lot of extra information I was hoping to discover.  Thanks, very much, for your help.  Copilot hallucinates again!


A 2N2222 will burn up at 3A
A 100 ohm shunt resistor will require 300V across it to pass 3A
Your 3A fuse will not - should not - blow at 3A. It depends on the curves provided by the manufacturer
Buying one or two fuses from a reliable source is better than buying a whole bunch of unreliable fuses
Testing one fuse will only tell you that that single (now unusable) fuse worked, not that the next fuse you pull out of the bag will also work


Very good answer & I appreciate it.  Your points make sense but I'd also like to know how to set up this kind of a test for my own understanding.  But I know that most of the time people here don't want to help with that.  Thanks.

Do you have a variable power supply capable of providing 3A?

A very good question.  I was going to also have to discover that myself.
I have a CIE (cleveland instit. of electronics) training lab power supply -- https://i.sstatic.net/J0UQrp2C.png

I agree with all parts of your answers (and others who have similar points), except the last one.   Certainly, if the pack of 100x fuses shows that 99 of them work and blow to within some spec, we can say with some amount of certainty that the 100th one will work, too?     Don't get me wrong -- don't skimp on safety components; not to mention other fuse characteristics like fast/slow, current breaking ability, etc. -- but testing a large number of parts to determine operation with some amount of reliability and confidence is Reliability Engineering, no?

Yes and that's what you pay for when you buy a fuse from Littelfuse or 3M or Bussmann and they will test way more than 99 fuses. These could be new manufacture, surplus, or QA rejects.
